# No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar'. R Cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, r.java-file

[image]First of all i want to say that i know this topics have been brought up lots of times. But i can't seem to find the solution for this problem.

This is some of the errors from the log:

```
/home/name/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:159: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.

/home/name/workspace/Projectname/res/values-v14/styles.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarStyle'.

/home/name/workspace/Projectname/res/values-v14/styles.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.

/home/name/workspace/Projectname/res/values-v14/styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
```

I'v made a custom theme, and im using `Actionbar`.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
```

All of this used to work, then i had to reinstall my `eclipse`, so i imported the project to the freshly installed one. And that is when the errors occurred.
The `R.File` is also missing.

Please help me, im starting to lose my mind becuase of this problem.

EDIT 1:

To clear things out. I added the android-support-v7-appcompat with this method (Adding libraries with resources):
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

The project build target on `android-support-v7-appcompat` is `Android` 4.0 and the project build target on my project is `Android` 2.3.3.

Is this right? Im not really sure what it should be like.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say exactly, but if you are using appcompt library,

Project(Right Click)--> Properties--> Android--> Library section--> Add--> appcompt library.

can you please check this once.

Edit :

- Compile with API Level 14 - when you compile your app with SDK level 9, the compiler doesn't know the elements shown in the error log
- Or Project(Right Click)--> Android Tools --> Add Support Library / Fix Project Property..

Comment: This is what it looks like for me. Took a screenshot.

Adding the picture in the OP.

Comment: Request you to mark this as an answer if this helps you.

Comment: Please look at my update Chitrang.
Greetings, Jesper